# Django get data from database

Tags: python, django

I need a function:

```
def GetData(self, column):
   query = UserData.objects.get(Username="Stack")
   return query.column
```

And use this:

```
ClassName.GetData(request, 'Email')
```

Unfortunately, of course, it will not work. How do I make it work the expected way?

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_data(self, column):
    query = UserData.objects.get(Username="Stack")
    return getattr(query, column)
```

To call it:

```
class_name.get_data('email')
```

`getattr` [python doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr).

I changed your function name because it's a bad idea to use `GetData` as function name. You should follow [pep8 convention](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) about functions and classes.

Also I don't know what is `ClassName`, but if your first parameter is `self`, you should call it with the `object.function()` where `object` is `self`.

Comment: And then `get_data(request.user, 'email')`, as far as I can read his question.

Comment: @AlexMorozov Thanks :).